# Spark from ASUS ROG STRIX B350 Motherboard

Tags: windows-10, ssd, motherboard

Last night after switching on my PC after installing an aged SSD, I saw a white spark to the bottom right hand side of my CPU (in between the CPU and the RAM, to be exact).

I suspect that my SSD was the culprit - it had burnt out.

After installing a new SSD, my motherboard appears to be working fine - so far. I had system freezes when updating Windows 10 (a 2015 version) from the internet but suspect that was the lack of AM4 drivers, because when I pulled the cable and installed Windows from USB stick it installed fine .

So far, the motherboard has been running for 3 hours solid downloading Windows updates etc.

How can I test all functionality of the motherboard? I really don't want to RMA it unless it's absolutely, absolutely broken.

I'm thinking of running Prime95 just to see if the system is stable, but what else can I do to ensure the motherboard is OK?

Comment: I'd probably run a Memtest as well as Prime95, and maybe run some disk tests too... fingers crossed it's nothing terminal.

Comment: I'm considering running "Hot CPU tester" to exercise all parts of the motherboard. Would that be enough to validate the motherboard is up to snuff and there's no weaknesses?  The motherboard is new so I can RMA it if absolutely necessary, but if it doesn't need it I'd be paying p&p for nothing.